# How to make new windows appear on "main" display in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors

How to make new windows and dialog boxes appear on specific display in multidisplay configuration, when desktop is extended to multiple displays?

Option "Make this your main display" does not help.

Comment: Most applications after being closed will open to the same screen on which they were located on when they were closed.  The same can be said by Windows Explorer windows for the most part.  I know of no easy fool proof way, to change the default behavior of opening new Windows Explorer windows, on the primary monitor.

Comment: Dialog boxes will usually appear on the same monitor where the main window is.

Answer (score 0):

I use a third-party plug in called DisplayFusion to manage windows and taskbars across multiple monitors.

I believe the free version allows you to specify which monitor programs open on. If not, there is also a 30-day trial of the full version.

If you go this route, go into the DisplayFusion settings and switch to the tab for Window Location (screenshot below). You may choose to open all or only certain programs on the specified monitor.

[image]